# Is the sentence "This whiteboard won't erase" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, middle-voice

I often see such phrases, and I am wondering whether they are strictly grammatically correct or not. It seems to me that the subject is "whiteboard" and the verb is "erase", which as far as I can tell is a transitive verb, hence requires a direct object.

On the other hand, it is obvious that the speaker is talking about some whiteboard which is unable of being erased, so that the whiteboard is actually the object of a verb, which should have been passive, whereas the subject is lacking.

The question is: Is this sentence grammatically correct or not?

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/erase) and [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=erase) list only the usual transitive usage.

Comment: There are a number of verbs can can be used in what is called the _middle voice_ ( or _mediopassive_ or _pseudo-passive_). For example: _She photographs well_ or _Her books don't sell, his do_.  I see no reason to call this usage of _erase_ ungrammatical.

Comment: Also known confusingly as both _ergative_ and _anti-ergative_ verbs, depending on theoretical stance; I recommend avoiding these terms. The "middle alternation" relates _The book is selling_ to _`X` is selling the book_, intransitive vs transitive. It isn't a "voice" in English, though it was in Greek.

Comment: How is it grammatically different from say "My car won't start"?  There may be something of a factual problem, since we don't generally expect whiteboards to erase, but it's perfectly possible to form grammatically correct sentences that don't correspond to reality.

Comment: Compare with "file won't delete" or "video won't play." This is very common usage in informal communication.

Comment: Is this a conventional whiteboard with physical dry-wipe pens and eraser or is it an electronic whiteboard? If it is the latter then "the whiteboard won't erase" makes sense. If it is the former then it is the _marks_ that won't erase. This can be the case when someone has written on a whiteboard in permanent marker, in that case the permanent marks won't erase but dry-wipe ones still will.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/133702/9161

Answer (score 27):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erase#:%7E:text=2a%20%3A%20to%20remove%20from,Sentences%20Learn%20More%20About%20erase) has already picked up this usage:

> **erase**:
>
> [intransitive verb]: to yield to erasure

There are a smallish number of examples on the internet, for instance

- *The new whiteboard erases flawlessly. The markers from my original purchase erased flawlessly on the replacement board as well,*

[[Amazon product review](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whiteboard+erases%22&ei=aWf1YJjqH9aU8gKI-IOICw&oq=%22whiteboard+erases%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEA0yBAgAEA0yBAgAEA0yBAgAEA0yBAgAEA0yBggAEA0QHjIGCAAQDRAeMgYIABANEB4yBggAEA0QHjIGCAAQDRAeOgcIABBHELADOgYIABAHEB5KBAhBGABQ6ZoBWP64AWDDvAFoA3ACeACAAbYBiAGpA5IBAzQuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjYwseJie_xAhVWilwKHQj8ALEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)]

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_ergative_verbs) also includes *erase* in its list of 'English ergative verbs'. But see John Lawler's comment above on terminology here. Also, some use the terms 'ergative usage' ('the glass broke', an event, punctive) and 'middle usage' ('glass breaks easily', describing a state) non-interchangeably; see [Your order has shipped](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107286/your-order-has-shipped/107292#107292).

Comment: To fully address the concerns that motivate the OP's question (rather than just the question as explicitly formulated), it should be noted that, even though ergative verbs (or however one wants to call them) tend to proliferate these days, many people resist that trend, and accept such use only when it gets really widespread. Such resistance is not confined to far-out prescriptivists; the people in the center of the prescriptivism-descriptivism spectrum also avoid using verbs as ergative until the usage is well established; they may perceive it as, at best, belonging to some jargon.

Comment: Isn't that an answer? I've hinted strongly at the lowish currency, but the fact remains that some usage panels have accepted the usage as grammatical. I'd probably only use it in informal contexts.

Comment: I have to say... "Exactly".

Comment: "The ink erased on the board" shows what's being called here an "ergative verb". "The markers erased on the board" is similar plus the metonymy of referring to the pen when you mean the substance it produces. But the OP asked about "This white board won't erase". This requires taking a noun even remoter syntactically from the subject and using it as subject.

Comment: Yes, Rosie. The transferred usage (the medium rather than the markings / data being _erased_) is not new for active and passive etc clauses:  << **erase** ... 1.2 Remove recorded material from (a magnetic tape or medium) ...
‘the tape [was/ ] could be magnetically erased and reused’ [= 'wipe clean/blank'] >> [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/erase)]

Comment: The verb *clear*, which has similar meanings, is well established as an [intransitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clear), e.g. "The clouds cleared" or (from M-W) "The symptoms cleared gradually." It seems logical to use *erase* in the same way.

Comment: ... and _remove_ and _delete_? And _disappear_  with a DO? 'It seems logical ...' as an argument for productivity in English is unsound.